# Hi, I am new to this, Can someone help me how can I fix this?

Tags: node.js

The error shown with it, no idea to fix this. can someone help?
I am new with this thing.

[image]

Comment: did you not see image?

Comment: Looks like the port 3000 is in use?

Comment: Port 3000 is already in use by another application (or your current nodejs app). Close all applications that using port 3000 or use an other port.

Comment: I upvote because: SOreadyToHelp!

Answer (score 1):

The error is really clear. The errorcode `EADDRINUSE` shows that the port you are using for your NodeJS application already is in use. Therefore your NodeJS application can't connect to this port anymore. Close all applications that is using that port or use a port that is not in use.

I see that you are using Nodemon. It's possible that your nodemon process hang. This can be the result of unexpected close of the terminal or errors in your application.

Check all running nodemon processes by using the command:

```
ps -ef | grep node
```

And kill the process by using:

```
sudo kill -9 <PID>
```

Comment: Thank You but not fix it yet! What is PID?

Comment: PID = process id

Comment: how do I get Process ID then?

Comment: `ps -ef | grep node`